# R: a "code vector" from string output

Tags: r, string, vector

In a script I extract colnames from a data.frame like this:

```
colnames(df[2:3]
[1] "Col1" "Col2"
```

In order to keep these strings in the script no matter if the rownumbers change in df before running the script again, I want this output to be in the script like:

```
c("Col1", "Col2")
```

My Code now:

```
setnames(df2, colnames(df2$[2:3]), colnames(df[2:3]))
```

and I want it like this:

```
setnames(df2, colnames(df2$[2:3]), c("Col1", "Col2")]
```

How can I achieve this easily?

Comment: Sorry but it seems to me that you haven't gotten the `R` logic. Just assign `mycols<-colnames(df)[2:3]`. Then you can reuse them when ever you want by calling `mycols`.

Comment: @5th: Sure, you are right. But I want to cover the case, that next time I run the script 'colnames(df)[2:3]' aren't "Col1" and "Col2" anymore because a column of df has been removed or added. Therefore I would like to retrieve the variable names "Col1" and "Col2" once, cause they will never change. In the past I did this by copying the console output in a vector, adding commas etc. But for many colnames that's a lot of work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> I would like to retrieve the variable names "Col1" and "Col2" once, cause they will never change. In the past I did this by copying the console output in a vector, adding commas etc.
>   The question is how to convert `colnames(df2)[2:3]` into `c("Col1", "Col2")` automatically

[`dput`](http://stat.ethz.ch/R-manual/R-devel/library/base/html/dput.html) writes an ASCII text representation of an R object.

```
dput(colnames(df2)[2:3])
```

Comment: That's it! Thanks man. The line just gained a place in my "very useful lines"-list :)

Answer (score 0):

Try `setnames(df2, colnames(df2)[2:3], c("Col1", "Col2"))` or `setnames(df2, colnames(df2)[2:3], colnames(df)[2:3])`

Comment: Sure, both lines work. The question is how to convert `colnames(df2)[2:3]` into `c("Col1", "Col2")` automatically